# Unable to send post request into a DJANGO API

Tags: python, python-requests, python-3.7, broken-pipe

I currentrly try to send a file through a post requests inside a DJANGO api. The sending is a failure it seems to be a lib problem but none of my actions worked.

I tried to update all my lib. The connection is aborted. Actually i'm lost and I don't really undestand why it doesn't work. I currently work with python 3.7 and i'm also using DJANGO API.

```py
import requests
import os

target_file = os.path.join('/path/to/file')
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:PORT/..../'
files = {'upload_files_form': open(target_file, 'rb')}
resp = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

```
BrokenPipeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
    601 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    355         else:
--> 356             conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
    357 

/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1228         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1229         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1230 

/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1274             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1275         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1276 

/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1223             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1224         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1225 

/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1054                         + b'\r\n'
-> 1055                 self.send(chunk)
   1056 

/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in send(self, data)
    976         try:
--> 977             self.sock.sendall(data)
    978         except TypeError:

BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    422                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 423                     timeout=timeout
    424                 )

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    648             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
--> 649                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
    650             retries.sleep()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    356             if read is False or not self._is_method_retryable(method):
--> 357                 raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
    358             elif read is not None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    684         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 685             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    686         raise value

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
    601 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    355         else:
--> 356             conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
    357 

/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1228         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1229         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1230 

/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1274             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1275         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1276 

/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1223             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1224         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1225 

/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1054                         + b'\r\n'
-> 1055                 self.send(chunk)
   1056 

/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in send(self, data)
    976         try:
--> 977             self.sock.sendall(data)
    978         except TypeError:

ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-edec929ccba7> in <module>()
----> 1 resp = requests.post(url, files=files)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py in post(url, data, json, **kwargs)
    108     """
    109 
--> 110     return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
    111 
    112 

 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     54     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     55     with sessions.Session() as session:
 ---> 56         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     57 
     58 

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    486         }
    487         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 488         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    489 
    490         return resp

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    607 
    608         # Send the request
--> 609         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    610 
    611         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    471 
    472         except (ProtocolError, socket.error) as err:
--> 473             raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
    474 
    475         except MaxRetryError as e:

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))
```

---

I expect requests to work with no error message.

Comment: is this the full error traceback?

Comment: yes it is, i edited it

Comment: well, it looks like there is a problem with network connectivity/sockets, not the `requests` lib

Comment: Yes I think so but I noted that the 'GET' requests worked perectly, not the POST..